How to enforce variable-types in bash?
I'm trying to create an err function to be used by bash-scripts. The function is supposed to emulate BSD's errx(3) -- printing the specified message and exiting with the code specified as the first argument:
function err {
    # set +u
    # The first argument must be an integer exit-code:
    if ! declare -i code=${1:?err called with no arguments}
    then
        code=70 # Use EX_SOFTWARE by default
    fi
    shift
    if [ -t 2 ]
    then
        # Use color -- red -- printing final errors to a terminal:
        printf "%s: \e[1;31m%s\e[1;0m\n" ${0##*/} "$*" >&2
    else
        printf "%s: %s\n" ${0##*/} "$*" >&2
    fi
    set -x
    exit $code
}

This works as expected, when invoked correctly, such as err 1 Date is empty. But, when invoked with no arguments or when the first argument is not numeric, an error in the declare-line is reported, but not handled: depending on whether -u is set, the script either dies right there on the declare-line, or code is initialized with 0, and the script exits with that -- instead of 70.
What am I doing wrong?

You can use a regular expression to test if the first argument is a number.

I'd still love to understand, why declare's failure is not handled here :(

Read the description of :? in parameter expansion. After printing the error message the shell exits.

But it does not necessarily exit -- it proceeds to printf and then exits with code 0...

Sorry, I misunderstood when you said "and the script exits with that".

Run the script with set -x enabled to see a trace of its execution.

As is typical for a script, your script is executing in a shell that isn't interactive (i.e. isn't reading commands from it's input and executing them) and so the following applies (from https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

${parameter:?word} If parameter is null or unset, the expansion of
word (or a message to that effect if word is not present) is written
to the standard error and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits....

Note the "if it is not interactive, exits" at the end of that. declare won't be called in this scenario because the parameter substitution happens first and causes the shell to exit.
Just do [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] or similar to test for integer input instead of calling declare, e.g.:
err() {
    local code=70
    if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        printf 'err() called with valid argument\n' >&2
        code=$1
        shift
    elif (( $# == 0 )); then
        printf 'err() called with no arguments\n' >&2
    else
        printf 'err() called with invalid argument %s\n' "$1" >&2
    fi
    #...
    exit "$code"
}

You should also consider using tput to produce colors, e.g.:
printf "%s: %s%s%s\n" "${0##*/}" "$(tput setaf 1)" "$*" "$(tput sgr0)" >&2

rather than hard-coding escape sequences as the former will try to produce the right color codes for the currently running terminal type while YMMV with the latter.

Ok, thanks for explaining the :? part. What about the argument not being numeric? Why does the declare -i not fail, when fed with a non-numeric assignment?

@MikhailT. you'd have to ask whoever provides declare why they made that choice. Looks like they decided to map any non-numeric string to zero and consider it a success - other tools such as awk do the same so it's not a crazy decision.
